# URL replacement from submitted comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am displaying a users website url in my comments. Everything works correctly on the view page, however I was wondering if I can change how the url is displayed.

Can I display http://google.com as Website? Or remove http, https and display as google.com?

Here is my current code:

```
<%= link_to comment.website, url_for(comment.website), target: '_blank' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `comment.website` returns string as: "http://google.com" you can use regex to trim everything up to "//" by using:

```
comment.website.remove(/.*\/\//)
```

this will however crash if `comment.website` will be nil so you can use slightly different syntax to write same code

```
comment.website.try(:remove, /.*\/\//)
```

so:

```
<%= link_to comment.website.try(:remove, /.*\/\//), url_for(comment.website), target: '_blank' %>
```

go and check http://rubular.com/r/ufMy2DjohW to play with the regex